# How to find the mode of 3 columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistical-mode

In SQL I have a table with 3 columns:

| Month1 | Month2 | Month3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

...and so on.

I need another column where it gives the mode of `Month1`, `Month2` and `Month3`.

My expected output is:

| Month1 | Month2 | Month3 | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

So far I have only calculated mode for a single column.  Not sure how we can do it horizontally by combining 3 columns.

Comment: This looks like you want the mode of 3 **columns** not 3 rows...

Comment: 3  columns but the mode should be row wise . For each row mode should be found between all the 3 column values

Comment: My point is your title ("How to find the mode between 3 rows in SQL?") implies you want the mode based on (1 column) different rows, not 3 columns (in 1 row). You want to mode of the row, not the mode of the rows (plural).

Comment: The OP *has* tagged their RDBMS, @Reporter . They've tagged [[tag:sql-server]].

Comment: @Larnu ok, the first editor has removed it and you addeded it again. Sorry for no reading of history ;-)

Comment: I've honestly no idea why that user made that suggestion, @Reporter , nor why the OP approved it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, can easily be expanded for *n* columns:

```
select month1, month2, month3, ca.val
from t
cross apply (
    select top 1 val
    from (values
        (month1),
        (month2),
        (month3)
    ) as v(val)
    group by val
    order by count(*) desc
) as ca
```

For RDBMS other than SQL server, replace `values(...)` with appropriate table value constructor, `cross apply` with lateral join/sub query inside select and `top 1` with limit/offset...fetch.

Comment: Overly complex for this *particular* case, but can be generalized to non-`bit` values, whereas the other answer cannot, so think it still deserves an upvote

Comment: @charlie the OP does not say that the columns are bits so.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Month1 + Month2 + Month3 <= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS mode
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I like how simple this is. Here's hoping the OP hasn't overly simplified their data and they actually have data that isn't just `0` or `1`.

Comment: @Larnu Actually, I wanted something even simpler using a modulus trick, but it didn't pan out.

Comment: @SalmanA No...I am saying doing something like taking the mod of the sum etc. to avoid an ugly `CASE` expression.  I certainly know the difference between the mode and the modulus.

Comment: This does return the mode though, @SalmanA . For 3 values that can only have the value of `0` or `1` then if the sum of those values is 1 or  less the most frequent value must be `0` (as at most only 1 of the values could have been `1`) and conversely if it is 2 or more, the most frequent value must be 1.